# Wildcard with LIKE operator in Meta query

Tags: meta-query

I have a form on a page that search property with a location field and I used the following meta query to process the search;

```
$location = preg_replace('/^-|-$|[^-a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $_GET['location']); 

    $meta_query = array( 'relation' => 'AND' );
    if($location) {
        $meta_query[] = array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'property_country',
                'value' => $location,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'property_city',
                'value' => $location,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'property_location',
                'value' => $location,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        );
    }
```

However, it works fine if I search for *New* but returns no results if I search for *New York*. How can I resolve this? Is there a way to add a wildcard before and after the `$location`? I tried adding `'*'.$location.'*'` but that did nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Have you `var_dump`ed `$location`?

`WP_Query`'s `meta_query` uses the class `WP_Meta_Query`, which automatically appends and prepends '%' to any *string* passed to it:

```
// From wp-includes/class-wp-meta-query.php:610 
switch ( $meta_compare ) {
            // ...
            case 'LIKE' :
            case 'NOT LIKE' :
                $meta_value = '%' . $wpdb->esc_like( $meta_value ) . '%';
                $where = $wpdb->prepare( '%s', $meta_value );
                break;
            // ...
}
```

So maybe try using `(string) $location` as the sql statement is prepared, and expecting a string -- that's what the `%s` means in the line `$where = $wpdb->prepare( '%s', $meta_value );`. You can cast your variable to a string like this:

```
$location = (string) preg_replace('/^-|-$|[^-a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $_GET['location']);
```

Comment: can you explain your last line a little more I don't quite get it.

Comment: @Naz I've updated my answer for clarity :)

Comment: I tried it but no joy.

Comment: @Naz I must have misread your original question. Please see my new answer above.

Answer (score 1):

Try joining the string with wildcards:

```
$location = implode('%', explode($location, ' '));
```